# Download file from a shared folder on network

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on an asp.net application. I am showing user the list of files from a shared folder on network and I want user to be able to download any file from the list. But I am not able to locate that file in the code I get `Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.` error.

Code block -

```
var uri = new Uri(filePath); // Here I get the error
var fName = Path.GetFullPath(uri.LocalPath);
var fileInfo = new FileInfo(fName);

var response = HttpContext.Current.Response;

response.Clear();
response.ClearContent();
response.ClearHeaders();

response.Buffer = true;

response.AddHeader("Content-Description", "attachment;filename="+fileInfo.FullName);
response.WriteFile(fileInfo.FullName);
response.End();
```

Please suggest how can I get to that file and give it to the response header so that it could be downloaded.

Comment: How your `filePath` value look like?

Comment: try `new Uri(filePath,UriKind.Absolute);` or `new System.Uri(filePath);`

Comment: @avijit server/somefolder/somefolder/file.txt

Comment: @jackjop, I tried `new Uri(filePath,UriKind.Absolute); or new System.Uri(filePath);` but same result.

Comment: Did you try adding "\\" before ther server string? E.g "\\server\filepath" ?

Comment: @SridharVenkat, yes I tried that and I am using that but its not working

Comment: `new Uri(@"\\server\somefolder\somefolder\file.txt")` should always work, check your escaping

Comment: Use: "\\\\server\\somefolder\\somefolder\\file.txt"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using the path in below format fixed the issue -

```
\\\\server\\somefolder\\somefolder\\file.txt
```

suggested by @avijit

Answer (score 4):

Use [Verbatim literal](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Strings.aspx):

```
var filePath = @"\\server\somefolder\somefolder\file.txt"
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use

```
response.WriteFile(filePath);
```

There is no reason to use a URI.

Comment: I get `Illegal characters in path.` exception after I removed first three line from above code and used `response.WriteFile(filePath);`

and file path is like `\\server\somefolder\somefolder\file.txt`

Comment: Make sure you escaped backslash \ in your UNC path, see this link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/371232/Escaping-in-Csharp-characters-strings-string-forma

Comment: Use: "\\\\server\\somefolder\\somefolder\\file.txt"